Bovine products in medicine - medical necessity
I live in US and try to avoid medicine containing bovine products such as gelatin, collagen, glycerin, stearic acid etc. I wanted to check that if someone is in hospital and needed some medicine immediately as part of treatment we cannot always determine each ingredient the medicine will contain and need to take that medicine. Also, if a baby needs immunization it will contain such ingredients but it is still a medical necessity. What does Hindu dharma says about that?

The Parshara Smriti(Ch 7,Sloka 35) says: During a civil commotion, or in exile, or when ill, or in misfortune, the first consideration is to preserve one's life ; practice of religion should at the time be postponed.

These are usually derived as byproducts so it doesn't further harm another animal but still feel uncomfortable consuming the medicine containing these ingredients
